# How can I exit/logout from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, command-line, ubuntu-14.04, psql

I'm new to psql and using psql command line on Ubuntu. What is the command to logout/exit from command line?

Thank you!

Comment: This is all documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

type `\q` and press `enter` to quit from psql from command line. In general the meta commands are preceded by `\` for eg- `\list` or `\l`: list all databases or `\dt`: list all tables in the current database

To switch databases:

`\connect database_name`

If that does not work, you can use `CTRL` + `D`. For more help on meta commands you can press `\?`

Since you are new to `psql` consider referring to the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html)

Comment: `\?` is useful!